# Alert work on chrome but not working on firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, function

I tried to make an alert. it works on chrome but not working when I try in firefox.

This is my html that trigger the function:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_submit">Submit</button>

$('#btn_submit').click(function() {
    setRating($('.checked').length, transaksi_id, menu_id);
    location.reload();
});
```

This is my routes

```
Route::post('/pesananSaya/setRating/{data}/{rating}', 'TransaksiController@setRatingPesananCust');
```

This is where I set the rating data

```
function setRating(rating, pesanan_id, id_menu) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pesananSaya/setRating/'+pesanan_id+'/'+rating,
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert("Nilai rating dimasukkan.");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public function setRatingPesananCust(Request $request, $id, $rating){
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $pesananId = $id;
    $data = Transaction::where('id', $pesananId)->get();
    foreach($data as $y) {
        $findRating = Rating::where('id_transaksi', $pesananId)->get();
        foreach($findRating as $y) {
            Rating::where('id_user', $y['id_user'])->where('id_transaksi', $y['id_transaksi'])->where('id_menu', $y['id_menu'])->update(['nilai_rating' => $rating]);
        }
    }
    return count($data);
}
```

Comment: Is everything working like `console.log()` or any javascript function

Comment: Please edit the question and add the HTML that triggers this function, the web route and the controller function

Comment: @Saly3301 my question has edited

Comment: @RobinSingh console.log() still working

Answer (score 0):

I think your firefox notification or popup maybe block by default.

Right-click on `webpage` > select `View Page Info` entry > select `Permissions` tab > modify Show `Notifications` or `Open Popup` Window items to suit.